# Check if elements of array are within bounds

Tags: python, performance

I have two arrays. One for lower and upper bounds, and one for my signals I measured. Now, I would like to know if all my signals are within the lower and upper bound.

```
x = np.random.normal(size=(10,))    # here, 10 signals
b = np.random.normal(size=(10, 2))  # lower and upper bound for each signal
```

Currently I do the following to check, if my signals are within their bound:

```
(b[:,0] < x) & (x < b[:,1])
```

Is there are faster way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your current speed is:

```
>>> a = lambda: (b[:,0] < x) & (x < b[:,1])
>>> timeit(a, number=100000)
0.40337433700000247
```

If you declare `b` as:

```
b = np.random.normal(size=(2, 10))
```

Then you shave off ~45%:

```
>>> q = lambda: (b[0] < x) & (x < b[1])
>>> timeit(q, number=100000)
0.22948266800000283
```

Comment: Nice! Can you explain why reshaping has such a large effect?

Comment: I would assume that it's because the "simple indexing" methods are faster than the "advanced indexing" methods. Unfortunately, I can't find the actual code for numpy indexing so I can't confirm this.

Comment: This is due to the way elements are stored in memory. The first solution does strided memory accesses while the second does contiguous ones. Strided memory accesses are slower (especially when the arrays are big). This is due to the hardware itself, not particularly numpy. See ["What every Programmer should know about memory"](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/).